# How to reverse one of the axes in a 3D Barplot Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, bar-chart, reverse

I have created the following 3-D barplot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymgnb.jpg)

Now I want to reverse the order of the axis labeled 1 to 5. The reverse function does not work. If I say reverse Y then it reverses the axis labeled 10 to 50 and with Z it reverses the up-down direction.

And I cannot tackle the axis of interest specifically at least I have not yet figured out how to and I am trying since quite a while.

Does anyone know how to handle such a problem specifically in a 3D barplot?

Thank you very much

yannick

Comment: for any plot, `xticklabel`. Just change them to what you want, in this case `{5,4,3,2,1}`.

Comment: thanks but i think this is just for changing the labels right? That is not what I would like. I want to reverse the order of the bars. The "bar row 5" is supposed to switch places with "bar row1".

Comment: then reverse the data? `fliplr` or `flipud`, depends on how you are calling it, but you haven't shown a [mcve]

Comment: thanks Ander Biguri, flipud did the trick. Yes somehow I tried to flip things before manually but it did not work. But now it does. Ok I hoped my graph would be illustrative enough. I remember for next time.